# Parallax Website Lags

Tags: css, html, nav, parallax

I am working on a parallax website ([here](http://www.techcrewnetwork.com/)) and the navigation div box is making the website lag.

The only way I can seem to make it smooth is to switch the navigation div out for an unsorted list.

But when I add a button to the website and click it:

HTML:

```
<div id="nope" class="coolButton">
    <h4><span>Nope.</span></h4>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#nope {
text-align: center;
}
h4 {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font-size: 600%;
line-height: 1em;
font-weight: bold;
text-align: center;
color: #fff;
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .3s linear;

}
h4:hover {
cursor: pointer;
text-shadow: 3px 3px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
-webkit-transform: scale(1.25);
-moz-transform: scale(1.25);
}
#nope:active:after {
display: block;
margin: 5em auto 0 auto;
content: url(kc.png);
}
h4 span {
padding: .1em .3em;
line-height: 1em;
-webkit-border-radius: .1em;
-moz-border-radius: .1em;
-webkit-transition: background-color .4s linear;

}
h4 span:hover {     
-webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
-moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
background: rgba(141,211,234,.35) url(grad.png) repeat-x top left;
}
.coolButton {
margin: 0;
padding: 10em;
font: small "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
background-position: 0 500%;
overflow: hidden;
-webkit-transition: background-position .4s ease-out;

}
.coolButton:hover {
background: url(space.png) no-repeat 50% 0;
}
```

The website is smooth!

I need a solution to keep the website smooth without changing the look of the navigation menu.

Comment: you can edit almost any element to look and behave like a completely different element. Are you sure the issue is with the div because of what you are saying? maybe the lag is caused by something else